# Who had followed me?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I want to make this question in passive
"Who had followed me?" I have this answer "Who had this been followed?"

Comment: I would say "Who(m) had I been followed by?" but it sounds a bit awkward to me.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please visit the help center for guidance on how to post a question. Our sister site ell.stackexchange.com would probably be more appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

## Auxiliaries are difficult:

If I am not wrong, I see the problem is how you conjugate the auxiliary verb "to be/have".

The painful truth about auxiliaries is that they are difficult to use, and moreso to "play" with.

The verbs *to do, to be,* and *to have* make auxiliaries even more confusing, because as an auxiliary, [they all share the same or similar meaning (learnenglish.de)](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbaux.html). What's even stranger is that [their auxiliary usages are all conjugations of the word "to be" (en.bab.la)](https://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/be) despite simultaneously being conjugations of their own verb.

## Solution to your problem:

If you persist on using "have/had" conjugations, the ***past perfect** passive* alternative was already provided to you by [Centaurus: "who(m) had [this] been followed by?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419046/who-had-followed-me#comment1002229_419046) However, he pointed out that this is awkward and unpleasant to read

So, use a different conjugation. A good conjugation is `was`: "who(m) was [this] followed by?"

Alternatively, you can use a *get* construction: "By who(m) got [this] followed."

Comment: _Was_ is not a different auxiliary from _had been_. It’s a different tense of the same auxiliary. It is in fact the only possible auxiliary and required to form a passive to begin with (unless you count _get_ constructions as true passives).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'll add that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd like to know more about this. `Has` is a conjugation of "to have;" `been` is a past participle conjugation of "to be." Is it not? I have never equated these two auxiliaries.

Comment: Both true. _Have_ is the auxiliary used with past participles to form the perfect aspect of verbs; _been_ is the past participle of _be_. _Has been_ is thus a present perfect form of _be_, just like _has followed_ is a present perfect form of _follow_. _Had been_ and _had followed_ are past perfect (also called pluperfect) forms of _be_ and _follow_, not forms of _have_. Similarly, _be_ is the auxiliary used with past participles to form passives: _was followed_ is past passive, _had been followed_ is past perfect passive.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you and note taken. Answer has been updated with informal citations and to fulfill your remarks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Where can I learn about _get_ constructions? I have never heard of this grammar before.

Comment: That’s just using _get_ as an auxiliary to form passives instead of _be_, as in “He got beaten up” instead of “He was beaten up”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is it possible to use _get_ in this circumstance? If so, I'd like to add it to my answer. Actually, I think I will ask that.