# Who got Jack followed by?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

Is this grammatically correct?

Definitely awkward, but is it grammatically sound?

You can say

> "Who got Jack followed/eaten/marked/killed/etc"

You can say

> "Jack got followed/eaten/marked/killed/etc by Jane"

But can you ask:

> "Who got Jack followed/eaten/marked/killed/etc by?"

**Edit:**

The question's equivalent is:

> "Who was Jack followed by?"

but I am playing around with `get` constructions.

Comment: I think "by who(m) got jack followed?" is what I am looking for.

Comment: All of the previous sentences are fine, But I'm struggling to understand what you are saying here. Do you mean "By whom did Jack get followed/marked/eaten/killed?" i.e. "Who followed Jack?" .You would be better off on English Language Learners with this type of question.

Comment: Unlike most other auxiliaries and modals, _get_ inflects like a regular verb, even when it acts like an auxiliary. That includes forming questions and negatives with _do_-support. Just like you can’t say “*What got you for Christmas?”, but instead have to say “What did you get for Christmas?”, so you have to ask “Who did Jack get followed by?” here.

Comment: @WS2 is there an article defining the difference between ELL and ELU? I would like to know why I should use ELL as a natural born American who natively speaks English.

Comment: Related: [Who had followed me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419046/who-had-followed-me)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is there a difference between _"By who jack got followed?"_ and your suggestion?

Comment: @forcedoutofanon Your question about "who got Jack...?" is confusing because it doesn't say what it is supposed to mean. I can make up an interpretation that makes everything work, but you haven't provided any such commentary, and the examples you give are not compatible with an understanding of question forming and the passive.

Comment: "Jane followed Jack", "Jack was followed by Jane", "Who was followed by Jane?", "Who was Jack followed by?". Those all are the same circumstance. Here's an etension: "Bob had Jane follow Jack", "Bob got Jane to follow Jack", Bob had Jack followed by Jane", "Bob had Jack followed", "Bob got Jack followed", "Who got Jack followed?". Is this the situation you want to describe? "Who got Jack followed by?" is not grammatical though. "Who _was_ Jack followed by?" is grammatical and its answer is "Jane".

Comment: Do you mean that someone who did not follow/eat/kill Jack personally either arranged for someone else to do it or was responsible for putting Jack in a situation where he was followed/eaten/killed in some way? I'm thinking of them employing a detective or contract killer; putting Jack in danger of being eaten by letting an animal out of its cage; or putting Jack in danger of accidental death, perhaps by leaving live wires exposed. If any of these is the case then the first and third sentences are OK. EG "Who got Jack eaten by the the lion?"

Comment: I've added some clarity.

Comment: *"Who got Jack followed by?"* is not grammatical but *"who got Jack followed **by Jane?"*** is correct and not even awkward if you know that Jane did the following, @forcedoutofanon. [Who followed Jack? Jane did, as directed by someone. So who got Jack followed by Jane?] If you *also* want to know who did the following you can ask *"who got Jack followed by whom?"* -- please see my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

OP edited the question after I posted my original answer:

> (...) can you ask:
>
> "Who got Jack followed/eaten/marked/killed/etc by?"
>
> Edit:
>
> The question's equivalent is:
>
> "Who was Jack followed by?"
>
> but I am playing around with *get* constructions.

Based on that clarification I am interpreting your question as,

> "can I grammatically rewrite "who was Jack followed by" as "who got Jack followed by?" where the passive form 'got' replaces the passive form 'was'?

As my original answer<sup>☆</sup> demonstrates (retained in the second half of this answer), your unorthodox construction is highly confusing mainly because a construction of the type 'got Jack followed' in such contexts has the common meaning of "got it done by someone else."

It is also a general convention that 'got' is usually applied only to the **object** of the basic form of the sentence which in this case is

> someone followed Jack.

So you can ask "who got followed" and the answer would be 'Jack'  but when you try to ask 'who followed Jack' in the passive voice the typical construction is (as you noted yourself)

> Who was Jack followed by?

Moreover, when you try to use the "who got" form in passive sense there is a general expectation (which may possibly not be grammatically binding) of a verb+by+object to follow 'got' as in

> who got duped by the trickster?
>
> who got hit by the bicycle?

or even a verb without by+object as in

> who got expelled for cheating?
>
> who got married in the holiday season?

Without conforming to known or typical syntactic patterns your sentence will unnecessarily confuse multiple readers as shown by the user response to your question in comments.

But is it strictly ungrammatical?

It is not grammatical, but not being a grammarian, I shall leave the explanation to the experts, who are invited to edit my answer here to clarify the reason.

Note: I am not saying that 'by' should necessarily be followed by a noun or noun phrase in every case. It is mainly expected in the context of sentences starting with "who got" and mainly because the 'who' here usually refers to the object of a verb. Otherwise it is perfectly okay for a sentence to end in 'by' as in "who did Jack get followed by?"

---

<sup>☆</sup>My **original answer**, based on the original (ambiguous) [version](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/419128/3) of OP's question which you can read in the edit history, is retained here to illustrate how completely the 'got' construction suggested by OP can confuse the listener or reader:

> **'By'** is [a preposition] regularly used to denote the *agent* (person or force) in passive constructions. [Example:] It is done by many; destroyed by fire.It also indicates means: Send it by airmail.

Source: www​.dictionary.com/browse/by

The general meaning of 'got' as in 'got Jack followed', 'got Jack beaten' etc is that somebody didn't do it themself, but arranged for it to be done by someone else, as noted by @BoldBen in comments under the question.

So in the sentence structure Got + object + verb (in past participle form) + by, ***the preposition 'by' also needs an object.*** The sentence cannot be left hanging on 'by.'

Who got Jack followed by... **by what/ by whom?**

So the sentence as written feels incomplete. If that was not your intention, then please edit your question to clarify.

Simply specifying who or what did the 'following', or how the 'following' was done (or even using the object pronoun 'whom' when you *also* want to know who did the 'following') will make the question grammatical:

> Who got Jack followed by land/ by air/ by sea?
>
> Who got Jack followed by the private detective?
>
> Who got Jack followed by whom?

and so on.

If you don't want to specify who did the 'following' nor ask about it using 'whom' then simply drop the 'by' which is no longer relevant without its object, and ask (as you have already done)

> Who got Jack followed?

"by someone / by some means" is implied here.

Note: although "who got Jack followed by whom?" is grammatical and perfectly sensible, a pedantic person might insist on using a comma, a conjunction or both as in

> Who got Jack followed, by whom?
>
> Who got Jack followed and by whom?
>
> Who got Jack followed, and by whom?

Comment: "by what/by whom" is the question at hand.

Comment: The reasoning behind this answer won't go through. Consider: "Who did Jack get followed by?"

Comment: I see now that OP has actually edited to clarify after I posted my answer though your interpretation made it most clear: I have rewritten my answer suitably, thanks for pointing out the difference @Araucaria.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Hi old bean. But your post still implies that there should be a noun phrase directly after *by*, when that isn't strictly true! :)

Comment: @EnglishStudent What I'm saying is that your grammatical reasoning is faulty. You say that *by* must have a following noun phrase, but this is not true.

Comment: I am not saying that 'by' should *necessarily* be followed by a noun or noun phrase, @Araucaria. I only said that in the context of sentences starting with "who got." Otherwise it is perfectly okay for a sentence to end in 'by' as in "who did Jack get followed by." I have edited the answer to clarify.